# Give background thread two handlers to talk to different activities?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I started Android a week ago and I have a design question.

I have two activities A and B. I'm currently on *activity A*. In *activity A* I start a thread that listens to network messages. On receiving ***start*** in the background thread over the network, I need to go into *activity B*.

**Question**: Can I simply call `startActivity(B.class)`  from the background thread?

If not, I suppose I use a `Handler` to call `startActivity(B.class)` from *activity A* thread.

**Question**: Will my background thread still continue to execute once *activity A*, the one that created it is destroyed, provided I take care that there are no dead references?

Eventually I receive a ***stop*** message in the background thread, again, over the network. Now I need to go back to *activity A* (or some other activity).

**Question**: Should I replace the handler instance in the background thread class with a new handler instance created in *Activity B*? I reckon I'll have to pass the thread object to *activity B* when I start it. I'll presumably have to take care of the race condition when switching out the handler instances.

All of this seems... complicated. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this? Services? Loopers? All of this is new and the tools/design choices are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple Activities then this isn't the ideal way of doing it.
Once Activity destroys your thread will have no more reference though it is running in the background. Use a singleton class to create the thread and register your respective handlers to that class, you will be able to communicate to the activities easily through these handlers.